# How can I prove that the binomial coefficient ${n \choose k}$ is monotonically nondecreasing for $n \ge k$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, binomial-coefficients

I want to prove that the binomial coefficient ${n \choose k}$ for $n \ge k$ is a monotonically nondecreasing sequence for a fixed $k$. How do I do this?

Comment: $\frac{nCk}{nCk-1}=\frac{n-k+1}{k}$. Or,$nCk>=<nCk-1$ according to:$n-k+1>=<k$,that is n-1>=<2k.The coefficient of  middle most term in a binomial expansion of the type: $(1+x)^n$: has the largest value for nCr.There may be two terms producing the largest binomial coefficient.

Comment: The post said that $n \le k$, which is most likely a typo; I corrected that.

Comment: Oh, sorry again. And thanks. :)

Comment: If you keep n fixed and increase k from zero to n , then nCk will first increase to a maximum value[this maximum value may get repeated twice] and them decrease.If you keep k fixed and then increase n the value of nCk will go on increasing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [the recursive formula for binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Recursive_formula)
$$
\binom{n}{k} = \binom {n-1}{k} + \binom{n-1}{k-1} \qquad (n, k > 0), 
$$
it is clear that $\binom{n}{k} \geqslant \binom{n-1}{k}$.

---

The claim is even more obvious when one thinks of the combinatorial interpretation of the binomial coefficient. Every $k$-subset of $\{ 1, 2, \ldots,  n-1 \}$ is also a $k$-subset of $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$; so it immediately follows that $\binom{n-1}{k} \leqslant \binom{n}{k}$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that!

Comment: @mcb It's alright. I removed that note from my answer now that the question is clear.

Answer (score 4):

Fix $k \geq 0$.  Show that $${n+1 \choose k} = \frac{(n+1)!}{k!(n+1-k)!} \geq \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = {n \choose k}.$$

But this follows whenever $n+1 \geq n+1 - k$, so...

Answer (score 1):

If if you keep $k$ fixed and increase $n$ the value of $\binom{n}{k}$ will increase monotonically.

$$
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k} &= \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
\\ &= \frac{n(n-1)....(n-k+1)}{k!} \tag{1}
\end{align*}
$$

If you differentiate the RHS of the above relation wrt to $n$ keeping $k$ constant, you will get a positive [or zero derivative: zero derivative occurs for $k=0$] derivative for $n \geqslant k$ [both $n$ and $k$ positive]. Therefore $\binom{n}{k}$ is a monotonocally increasing function of $n$ when $k$ is kept constant.

You may consider the function expressed by $(1)$ as a continuous function of $n$ [$k$ is of course a fixed integer]. But our interest will be on the integral values of $n$. These values occupy discrete positions on the domain of continuous function considered.
For $k=0$, the function is defined to be a constant ($=1$).

Comment: Dear Anamitra, I cleaned up your post a bit and improved the TeX. Hope that it's ok. I liked your answer and upvoted it.

Comment: Thank you very much.I would try to improve my capabilities with LaTex.