# Greatest value of the binomial coefficient.

Tags: inequality, optimization, binomial-coefficients, combinations

How should I prove the greatest value of the binomial coefficient $C(n,r)$ occurs for $r=\left[\cfrac{(n+1)}{2}\right]$ ?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722952/how-do-you-prove-n-choose-k-is-maximum-when-k-is-lceil-frac-n2-rceil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the maximum  binomial coefficient consider x=a=1.By the above theorem max term will give us the max binomial coefficient.
r=[n+1/1+1]=[n+1/2]

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $C(n,r+1)=C(n,r)\cdot\frac{n-r}{r+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Look at Pascals' Triangle. Notice where the maximum values of each row occur.