# Show that $\binom{n}{k}< \binom{n}{k+1}$ if and only if $k < (n-1)/2$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inequality, binomial-coefficients

Show that $\binom{n}{k} < \binom{n}{k+1}$ if and only if $k < \frac{n-1}{2}$ and then use this to deduce that the maximum of $\binom{n}{k}$ for $k=0,1,\dots,n$ is $\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722952/how-do-you-prove-n-choose-k-is-maximum-when-k-is-lceil-frac-n2-rceil

Answer (score 4):

*Hint*: If you're able to use the formula $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}$, then it's just arithmetic:
$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}= \frac{k+1}{n-k}\frac{n!}{(k+1)! (n-k-1)!}=\underbrace{\frac{k+1}{n-k}}_{\substack{\text{when is this} \\ \text{$<1$?}}} \binom{n}{k+1}.$$

For the second part, we can use that $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$.

Comment: I get up to part where you substituted (k+1), but where did (k+1)/(n-k) come from?

Comment: We combine $\frac{1}{k!}=\frac{k+1}{(k+1)!}$ and $\frac{1}{(n-k)!}=\frac{1}{(n-k)(n-k-1)!}$, to get $\frac{1}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac{k+1}{n-k}\frac{1}{(k+1)!(n-k-1)!}$.

Comment: Why is 1/k! = (k+1)/(k+1)! and not just 1/(k+1)! ?
similarly, shouldn't 1/ (n-k)! = 1/ (n-k-1)!

Comment: By definition of a factorial, $(k+1)!=(k+1) \times k!$; after that, we just rearrange to get $\frac{1}{k!}=\frac{k+1}{(k+1)!}$.

Comment: could you elaborate on the second part?

Comment: We have $(k+1)!=(k+1) \times k!$.  We divide both sides by $k!$ to obtain $\frac{(k+1)!}{k!}=k+1$, then divide both sides by $(k+1)!$ to obtain $\frac{1}{k!}=\frac{k+1}{(k+1)!}$.

Answer (score 2):

I like using

$${n\choose k}={n-1\choose k}+{n-1\choose k-1}$$

and induction. Then you check the base case.

The pictoral representation is Pascal's triangle, you are adding bigger numbers when you go farther along (up to the line of symmetry) so the values get larger. You even get the "only if" direction along the way thanks to the symmetry in the induction.

Comment: Oops, thanks. I fixed the typo!