# Prove ${2n \choose r+1}$ is maximum for $r=n$

Tags: combinations

**Question:**

Prove ${2n \choose r+1}$ is maximum for $r=n$

**My Efforts:**

$$\begin{align} {2n \choose r+1} > {2n \choose r} 
& \Leftrightarrow \frac{(2n)!}{(r+1)!(2n-r-1)!} > \frac{(2n)!}{r!(2n-r)!}\\
&\Leftrightarrow\frac{(2n-r)!}{(2n-r-1)!}>\frac{(r+1)!}{r!} \\
&\Leftrightarrow 2n-r > r+1 \\
&\Leftrightarrow ,r<n-\frac{1}{2} \\
\end {align}$$

I don't know how to move ahead.

---

P.S. my teacher gave me clue to begin with $ {2n \choose r+1} > {2n \choose r} $

Comment: So that inequality is valid as long as $r<n$, and then it reverses at $r=n$ onwards. What does that tell you about which term is largest?

Comment: Alternatively, solve that inequality for $r$ and see what you get.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722952/how-do-you-prove-n-choose-k-is-maximum-when-k-is-lceil-frac-n2-rceil

Comment: Is the problem statement correct? Looks to me that the correct statement should be $\binom{2n}{r}$ is maximum when $r=n$. That is, in fact, what the answer below is proving.

Comment: @RickGoldstein I think for n=r is equivalent to when n=r. If it is not than answer given is incorrect!

Comment: @hey I don't understand what you're saying. Consider $n=1$. Then the binomial coefficients are $\binom{2}{0} = 1$, $\binom{2}{1} = 2$, and $\binom{2}{2} = 1$. The maximum value is the middle one, which, in your formula would be $r=0$, *not* $r=n=1$.

Comment: @RickGoldstein I am learning combination for first time, even I am not getting it. I don't know whether what I have done is correct. I just moved ahead with my teacher's clue. So it's better tomorrow i will ask my teacher to help me and then i will post it as answer.

Comment: You can't prove something that isn't true. Not if you're a mathematician, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\binom{2n}{r}\geq\binom{2n}{r-1}\Leftrightarrow \frac{2n-(r-1)}{r!(2n-(r-1))!}\geq\frac{r}{r!(2n-(r-1))!}$

$\Leftrightarrow 2n-r+1\geq r\Leftrightarrow 2r\leq2n+1$

Let's do it the other way now.

$\binom{2n}{r}\geq\binom{2n}{r+1}\Leftrightarrow \frac{r+1}{(r+1)!(2n-r)!}\geq\frac{2n-r}{(r+1)!(2n-r)!}$

$\Leftrightarrow 2r\geq 2n-1$

Therefore if $r$ is the maximum then $2n-1\leq 2r\leq2n+1$

Therefore $2r=2n$. Hence $r=n$

---

PS : For writing $\binom{a}{b}$ in $\LaTeX$, use *\binom{a}{b}* rather than *{a\choose b}*

Comment: I had spend around 15 minutes to figure out, how to write it! Thanks, that will also equally helpful :)

Comment: @hey If that was helpful, you can upvote and click the _accept answer_ button :)

Comment: +1 This is a good proof, but note my comment above. You have proven that $\binom{2n}{r}$ is maximal when $r=n$, *not* that $\binom{2n}{r+1}$ is maximal. I think the OP is a little confused, and the question statement need editing.

Comment: @RickGoldstein Thanks, I hadn't seen that. I edited it.

Comment: @Hippalectryon - I think you misunderstood me. Your original proof is correct. Your edited proof is *also* correct, but in neither case have you proven the statement of the original question, because that question is misstated. Also, your statement near the end that $\binom{2n}{n}=\binom{2n}{n-1}$ is not correct--substitute $n=1$ to verify. Think about it this way: a binomial expansion of order $2n$ has $2n+1$ terms, with the largest binomial coefficient being the middle one, i.e. $\binom{2n}{n}$.