# Inequality involving binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, exterior-algebra

I am reading a proof in which it is claimed that for all $2 \leq k \leq n-2$, the following inequality holds $$k(n-k) < {n \choose k} - 1.$$

Why is this true? I've tried to show this by induction on $n$ and I've also tried to find different objects to use in a counting argument, but I've had no success so far.

I would also like to learn general techniques for deriving such inequalities. I feel a little clueless about how to get started on this one.

To provide more information, this appears in the second proof [here](http://www.math.toronto.edu/vtk/1300Fall2014/hw8sol.pdf) that for any $2 \leq k \leq n-2$, there exists a $k$-covector on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is not a blade, i.e., not decomposable into a wedge product of $k$ covectors.

**Edit:** I originally made a mistake and had written a nonstrict inequality. I have modified the inequality to be strict.

Comment: for $k=1,n-1$ is also hold.

Comment: @Phicar: Thanks, I meant to have a strict inequality there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

- By AM-GM $\;k(n-k) \le \frac{n^2}{4}\,$.
- The binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$ for fixed $n$ and variable $k$ are monotonically increasing for $k=1,2,\dots,\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ then monotonically decreasing from $k=\lfloor (n+1)/2 \rfloor\,\dots,n\,$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722952/how-do-you-prove-n-choose-k-is-maximum-when-k-is-lceil-frac-n2-rceil) for example). Therefore $m = \min \left\{\binom{n}{k} \mid 2 \le k \le n-2\right\}=\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\,$.
- $2 \leq k \leq n-2$ implies $n \ge 4\,$, and $\frac{n^2}{4} \lt \frac{n(n-1)}{2} - 1$ for $n \ge 4\,$.

Piecing together:

$$k(n-k) \le \frac{n^2}{4} \lt \frac{n(n-1)}{2} -1 = m -1 \le \binom{n}{k} -1$$

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was hoping there would be a simpler answer, because I don't know how I would come up with this on my own, but at least the steps make sense to me.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit on your intuition or how you came up with this solution? Is it just from practice? E.g., I wouldn't have known to expect that AM-GM is "sharp enough" that it wouldn't spoil the rest of the estimate.

Comment: @MatthewKvalheim The inequality itself is rather weak. What the above proves is in fact the stronger statement $k(n-k) \lt \binom{n}{k'} - 1$ for any $2 \le k, k' \le n-2\,$. As far as intuition, I knew that the binomial coefficients go "*up and down*" from $k=1$ to $k=n$ and was just checking on how that relates to the LHS, when I realized that the stronger statement does in fact hold. Given how loose the proposed inequality is (and, maybe, the `combinatorics` tag as well) I would not be surprised in the least if a more elegant one-line combinatoric proof existed.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. Just one more thing: can you offer any intuition about using AM-GM specifically, or did you just try it arbitrarily and saw that it was sufficient?

Comment: @MatthewKvalheim AM-GM was just the most succinct way to justify it. You could as well look at $\,f(k)=k(n-k) = -k^2 + n\,k\,$ as a quadratic function in $k\,$, and note that it has a maximum (since the leading coefficient is negative) at $k = n/2\,$, which maximum is $f(n/2) = n^2 / 4\,$.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Not a very rigorous answer, but:

wlog assume $n-k > k$.

We can rewrite the inequality as :

$n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-k+1) - 1 \geq k(n-k)k!$

There are k+2 "things" being multiplied together on the LHS, and k+2 "things" on the RHS.

Clearly 
$n > n-k, \\
n-1 > k, \\
n-2 \geq k,
n-3 \geq k-1 \\
n-4 \geq k-2 \\
\vdots \\
n-k+1 \geq 1$\

therefore the LHS is strictly greater than the RHS, and since all are integers (assuming?), we have the extra "-1", changing it to a soft (nonstrict) inequality.

Comment: are you sure you can rewrite the inquality in this way: $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-k+1) - \color{red}{1} \geq k(n-k)k!$.... I think that $1$ should be $k!$.

Comment: @MANMAID good catch, I think you're right.