# Describe the range of any Combination (nCr) given n

Tags: combinations

I'm working on a problem of **finding the maximum of $\binom{n}{r}$ in terms of $n$, where $r\le$n.**

Now, I know that $\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1} +...+\binom{n}{n}=2^n$, so $\binom{n}{r}$ should be no more than $2^n$. And I find that $\binom{2}{1}=2$ which is half of $2^2$ and $\binom{3}{1}=3$ which less than half of $2^3$, but it seems not a strict proving. It seems like there is a relation between $n$ and the ratio between the largest $\binom{n}{r}$ and $2^n$ with $n$ given. Maybe reciprocal? Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try a few examples with $n=2,3,4,5$. The largest binomial coefficient is the middle one (or two of them) - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2496836/combinatorial-proof-that-central-binomial-coefficients-are-the-largest-ones), for example, or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2984998/proving-that-for-n-equiv-0-pmod2-we-get-n-choose-0-n-choose-1?noredirect=1&lq=1). And the value is related to Catalan numbers, see the OEIS entry in the answer below.

Comment: Check this post too: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722952/how-do-you-prove-n-choose-k-is-maximum-when-k-is-lceil-tfrac-n2-rcei

Comment: For simplicity, assume that $m=2n$ is even. Then we have
$$
\binom{2n}{n} \operatorname*{\sim}
\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}.
$$
This is the maximum in terms of $n$, asymptotically. See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1442351/stirling-approximation-of-binom2nn).