# Natural injection $\binom{[n]}{k} \to \binom{[n]}{k+1}$ for $0\leq k < \frac n 2$.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let $n$ and $k$ be integers with $0\leq k < \frac n 2$, and denote $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

There are a myriad ways one can show that $\binom{n}{k} \leq \binom{n}{k+1}$, but I can't think of any "natural" injection $f: \binom{[n]}{k} \to \binom{[n]}{k+1}$.

I could of course just construct such map by settting $\binom{[n]}{k} = \{A_i : 1\leq i \leq \binom n k\}$ and $\binom{[n]}{k+1} = \{ B_i : 1\leq i \leq \binom n {k+1} \}$ and $f(A_i)=B_i$ for all $1\leq i \leq \binom n k$ but that would feel "over-engineered". Such a simple statement should correspond to a simple and intuitive map, shouldn't it?

Comment: @DavidK If $S$ is a set and $k$ is an integer, then $\binom{S}k$ is defined to be the set of size-$k$ subsets of $S$. This is a common convention.

Comment: $X \subset f(X)$ would be nice if possible, too.

Comment: It seems you can just add one element to every set in $\binom{[n]}{k},$ but which element?

Comment: @DavidK And in an invertible way: Given $f(X)$, it must be possible to figure out which element must be removed to get back to $X$.

Comment: I gave an injection in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2894340/177399s), one that satisfies $X\subset f(X)$. Should I close as a duplicate, or reproduce that answer here?

Comment: @MikeEarnest excellent! Thank you!