# Proving $n!k! \le (n+k-1)!$ for positive integers $n \ge 1$, $k \ge 1$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

### The Question

Does the following inequality hold:
$$n!k! \le (n+k-1)! \quad \text{for positive integers} \quad n \ge 1,\\ k \ge 1  \text{.}$$
I *suspect* it does but I'm at a loss on how to prove (or *disprove*) this.

#### What I've tried

I've been able to show that the simpler inequality:
$ n!k! \le (n+k)!\\ $ holds by dividing both sides by $k!$ so that $n$-terms remain on both sides:
$ \prod_{p=1}^{n} p \le \prod_{p=1}^{n} (p+k) $
which is clearly true for $k \ge 1$.

Applying the same process for the original inequality yields
$ \prod_{p=1}^{n} p \le \prod_{p=1}^{n-1} (p+k) $
which feels inconclusive due to the right-hand-side having one fewer terms than the left-hand-side.

I don't have much of a background in combinatorics so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: For fixed $n$, use induction on $k$.

Comment: A warning, a first inclination might have been to try to claim that $n!k!$ is always a divisor of $(n+k-1)!$ (*and thus smaller*) by way of some combinatorial argument that $\binom{n+k}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{n+k}$ should have been some answer to a counting problem, however that doesn't work, noting as a counterexample something like when $n=k=p$ for some prime $p$, the factor of $p$ will have appeared in the denominator thrice when expanded while only appearing in the numerator twice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the distinct subsets $A_1 = \{1, \ldots, n\}$, $A_{2} = \{2, \ldots, n+1\}, \ldots,$ $A_{k} = \{k, \ldots, n+k-1\}$ of size $n$.

It follows that $k \leq \binom{n+k-1}{n}$. Rearranging yields the original inequality.

Comment: I'd give this +2 if I could.  Nice argument.

Answer (score 2):

By writing $N=n+k$ the claim is equivalent to $\binom{N}{n} \geq N$. To prove this we may assume $n \leq N/2$, and then use that these binomial coefficients $\binom{N}{1},\binom{N}{2},\dotsc$ are in fact non-decreasing, starting with $\binom{N}{1}=N$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2496836/combinatorial-proof-that-central-binomial-coefficients-are-the-largest-ones), you can directly verify $\binom{N}{n-1} < \binom{N}{n}$).

Answer (score 2):

For arbitrarily fixed $n\geq 1$, we argue by [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) on $k$. For $k=1$, the desired inequality holds trivially. Assume that the inequality holds for some $k\geq1$, i.e., $$n!k! \le (n+k-1)!\tag{$*$},$$ we prove that it holds also for $k+1$, hence our aim is to show that
$$n!(k+1)!\le(n+k)!\tag{$**$}.$$
By our induction assumption $(*)$, we have
$$n!(k+1)!=n!k!(k+1)\le (n+k-1)!(k+1).$$
To show $(**)$, it suffices to prove that $(n+k-1)!(k+1)\le(n+k)!$, which is equivalent to $k+1\leq n+k$, and this follows from $n\geq 1$. Hence $(**)$ holds and thus the inequality is porved by induction.

Answer (score 1):

A combinatorial proof here: $n-1$ adults and $k$ children stand in a line.

**Scenario 1**

They can stand in any order they want. The number of possibilities is $(n+k-1)!$

**Scenario 2**

There are no adults between any two children. The children can be arranged in $k!$ ways. Subsequently, the $n-1$ adults and $1$ group of children can be arranged in $n!$ ways. Therefore the number of possibilities is $n!k!$.

**Conclusion**

Clearly the number of possibilities in scenario 1 is greater or equal to that in scenario 2. Therefore we obtain what we need:

$$
(n+k-1)!\geq n! k!
$$