# What is the greatest term in $(1+\frac{1}{2}x)^{12}$ when $x=\frac{1}{2}\;?$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

The question is find the greatest term in $\bigg(1+\dfrac{1}{2}x\bigg)^{12}$ when $x=\dfrac{1}{2}$.

I know how to expand using binomial expansion but there no background in my book related to this question, the only thing that I know to expand it and find out the total 13 terms and then pick the greatest but term but that is not the way as I think.

Comment: Please reflect on whether your title tells other users anything about your question?

Comment: Try computing the first few terms. Maybe you will see a pattern.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722952/how-do-you-prove-n-choose-k-is-maximum-when-k-is-lceil-tfrac-n2-rcei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

$$\left(1+\frac14\right)^{12}=\sum_{k=0}^{12}\binom{12}k4^{-k}$$

But we have

$$\binom{12}{k+1}4^{-(k+1)}\le\binom{12}k4^{-k}\implies\frac{12!}{(k+1)!(12-k-1)!}4^{-k-1}\le\frac{12!}{k!(12-k)!}4^{-k}\iff$$

$$\frac{(12-k)!}{4(12-k-1)!}\le\frac{(k+1)!}{k!}\iff\frac{12-k}4\le k\iff5k\ge12\iff k\ge3$$

Thus the sequence $\;\left\{\binom{12}k4^{-k}\right\}_{k=0}^{12}\;$ is monotonic descending for $\;k\ge 3\;$, so...what can you deduce from here.

Answer (score 1):

I very much like DonAntonio's answer, however for this simple example I think your textbook expected a solution along the following lines:

Each term in the expansion is
$$\binom {12}k\Big(\frac{1}{2}x\Big)^k = \binom {12}k\Big(\frac{1}{4^{k}}\Big)$$
when $x=\tfrac 12$.

Now $4^{k}$ is increasing and grows faster than $\binom{12}k$, so we just need to find when $\binom{12}k/4^k$ first decreases:
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{c|cc|c}
k&4^k & \binom{12}k & \binom{12}k/4^k\\
\hline
0 & 1&1 & 1\\
1 & 4 & 12 & 3\\ 
2 & 16 & 66 & 4.1\\ 
3 & 64 & 220& 3.4
\end{array}
\end{align}
Thus we get a decrease when $k=3$, and so the largest term occurs when $k=2$.