# Find maximum and minimum value of: $\binom{16}{k}+\binom{16}{k-1},k\in N$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Find maximum and minimum value of: $\binom{16}{k}+\binom{16}{k-1},k\in N$

Now, $\binom{16}{k}+\binom{16}{k-1}$ is same as $\binom{17}{k}$

I think that minimum value would be for $k=17$, which is $1$. But what would be the maximum value?

Comment: As $k$ gets closer to $\frac{17}2$, $\binom{17}k$ gets bigger

Comment: "*as $k$ gets closer to $\frac{17}{2}$*" of course is in specific reference to the $17$ in $\binom{17}{k}$.  More generally $\binom{n}{k}$ is maximized for $k$ closest to $\frac{n}{2}$.

Comment: Look up Pascal's triangle and find the maximum value of ${3 \choose k}$, ${4 \choose k}, {5 \choose k}$ and so on.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722952/how-do-you-prove-n-choose-k-is-maximum-when-k-is-lceil-tfrac-n2-rcei)

Comment: If you are allowed $k=17$ so $\binom{16}{17}+\binom{16}{17-1}=1$, then $k=18$ and $\binom{16}{18}+\binom{16}{18-1}=0$ is an even smaller result