# Evaluating $\lim_{m \to \infty} \binom{m}{k} \cdot 2^{-m}$ for $0 \leq k \leq m$.

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients

I am attempting to evaluate the limit $\lim_{m \to \infty} \binom{m}{k} \cdot 2^{-m}$ for $0 \leq k \leq m$, and I have been able to confirm via Mathematica that this limit is indeed 0. How would one actually go about proving this?

Comment: Is $k$ fixed, or can it grow with $m$?

Comment: It can grow with $m$ too.

Comment: One way then could be to use Stirling's approximation -- the maximum over all $k$ (up to some annoying distinction of cases for $m$ even or odd) if for $k=m/2$, and that one can handled via Stirling's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity let $m$ be even. $\binom{m}{k}$ is largest when $k=\frac12m$ [see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722952/how-do-you-prove-n-choose-k-is-maximum-when-k-is-lceil-tfrac-n2-rcei)]. Hence $$\binom{m}{k}2^{-m}\le\frac{m!}{(m/2)!(m/2)!}2^{-m}.$$ Now using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) you can find the limit to be zero.

Comment: Nice! This is quite a clever solution -- that bound for the binomial makes a lot of intuitive sense, but how would one make a rigorous argument for it?

Comment: Which is the part that you would like to make rigorous?

Comment: That C(m, k) is largest when k = m / 2. This is obviously true, but what is the rigorous argument for it?

Comment: Just added a link, hope that it proves useful.